# Can't access CentOS in VirtualBox

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I have a CentOS installed in VirtualBox. I have a web server running within it but for some reason I can't seem to be able to access it from outside.

The Ip address reported from CentOS is: 10.0.2.15
The web server is on port 8080.

I can curl 127.0.0.1:8080 and I get correct response (from CentOS).

Iptables is not running.

I have network enabled in VirtualBox (NAT) and I have set a forwarding rule
127.0.0.1,80,,8080

For some reason this does not get me anything. When I try to curl 127.0.0.1, I get: "curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused"

I also figured out that if I try to curl from Guest OS using it's public IP I still get the same error with connection refused.

Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: This is because you're using the NAT networking mode. Try the Bridged one instead.

Comment: The thing is that I'd like to know why this NAT does not work as I believe I have configured it.

Comment: I tried swithcing to bridged mode and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You have to make sure you web server binds to _all_ IP address interfaces, usually with a `*`. Otherwise it will only listen to connections from localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual machine is behind NAT and won't be accessible from the outside.

You can either configure [NAT port forwarding](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward) or change the interface type to bridge (so the VM has a physical presence in your local network). If you only need to access it from your machine, the Host-Only Adapter type will be enough.

Comment: Well, I believe I have set up port forwarding. I have set (in VirtualBox settings) Host IP to be 127.0.0.1, Host Port to be 9090, Guest IP to be 10.0.2.15 and Guest Port to be 8080. When I use "curl 127.0.0.1:9090" I don't get any response. It seems like curl is hanging... If I use "curl 127.0.0.1:8080" from guest VM I get correct response - Hello World.

Comment: sometimes you need to restart your VM. Also check that the Guest IP is the one that is listed for eth0, rather than the virbr0 one.

Comment: No that did not help. But I realised that if I use "curl 10.0.2.15:8080" from guest OS I still get the same error which is a bit weird as this should be machines public IP...

Comment: Ok, sorted it out. For some stupid reason webserver which I use does not distinguish difference between 127.0.0.1/localhost/ip-address.